# Add anchor tag to wordpress site header customization

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a Wordpress site that needs some fixes and one of my issues is, that I can't add an anchor tag to the ***Customize page*** options list. What I mean is the following:
[image]

This is my information module that I can change, but for now it accepts only the `<strong>` tags along with some others that have been added to the array() that it is using. Here is the code that is working for me now, but as you can see, the anchor has been hardcoded into it:

```
<div class="text">
    <a id="mainPhone" href="tel:02086109182">
        <?php echo wp_kses( nl2br( $header_phone ), array( 'br' => array(), 'strong' => array(), 'span' => array() ) ); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I switch from this to something like this:

```
<div class="text">
    <?php echo wp_kses( nl2br( $header_phone ), array( 'br' => array(), 'strong' => array(), 'a' => array(), 'span' => array() ) ); ?>
</div>
```

I have added `'a' => array()` to it, and as it seems it adds an anchor to the content (it gets underlined and etc.) but It is not clickable (my guess is that the href attribute needs to be added in some way?).

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to be able to insert HTML in the customiser, why not just leave it unformatted?

Comment: How can I do this? This Theme that it is using is not my work, so I am very strict on such changes.

Comment: Oh, well you can't then. I'd suggest creating a child theme, and re-creating the header file so you can have it how you like?